# cmus not working on Arch Linux

Tags: terminal, arch-linux, cmus

When I try to run cmus from the terminal , I got this

bhaskar@ArchLinux_12:18:39_Mon May 20:~>cmus

cmus: /usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0: version `LIBSYSTEMD_243' not found (required by cmus)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was me. Because of systemd bug, I masked few packages and never get back to the bug tracker to see that bug got fixed in some time. So, I unmasked those packages and update those and cmus start working like a charm.

Updated packages : systemd systemd-libs sysvcompat

But, somebody somewhere pointed out to me that some component is optionally built with systemd and that why the problem, that can be eliminated, if you decided to do it yourself. But, unfortunately, I pull down system package and it was built with that dependency.

If you use cmus on Arch, you have to go with "their" options or build it yourself.